# Javascript_Include_Tag Not Working. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3 view I have the following code:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "home" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "home-style" %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason neither include shows up. If I manually type in `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/home.js">` everything works fine, but I can't seem to get anything to show up using `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag`. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

The generated HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>        
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1310704251" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1310704251" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1310723736" type="text/javascript"></script>                                                        
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="uCZdtztzlgDDUqTG+FvjhuQL6hFFAnwXTcAnvMGX4Ug="/> 
</head> 
<body> 



</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what is the full name of javascript file?

Comment: the full file file name is home.js

Comment: /public/javascripts. Now that I dig a little deeper I've realized that neither the javascript nor the stylesheet is getting included, the stylesheet was only included because it had been included in the application.html.erb layout - it wasn't being included from this file. So basically content_for :head is not working for me.

Comment: Fixed it. I need a <%= yield :head %> in the application layout. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I realized. Do you have '<%= yield :head %>' in your layout?

Comment: Besides, scripts should live just before the end of the body. You should move them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you add `<%= yield :head %>` in your application.html.erb file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```